# Can I mount another drive to "/", act like adding additional disk to "/"

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization

System:
Ubuntu

Currently, the server has 50G disk, df output as below.

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/hda1             49448752   1445164  45491668   4% /
none                   1278760       176   1278584   1% /dev
none                   1283492         0   1283492   0% /dev/shm
none                   1283492        36   1283456   1% /var/run
none                   1283492         0   1283492   0% /var/lock
```

It has 200G at /dev/xvdb not yet mounted. Is it possible to mount /dev/xvdb to "/", so make it to ~250G total at "/" (kind of like expand/extend current "/" directory) ?

If possible, how may I do so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add it to / and then go to 250G (at least not easily). by the way, I propose to mount it to /home and then put all your datas to this disk. The system will have 50G and your datas 250G.

At the next install, you will just need to format the system and you will not loose your datas.

Comment: the system already has /home directory, can still mount /dev/xvdb to /home?

Comment: @gilzero: No, you can not mount the same point twice!

Comment: You can't mount twice. But you can copy your actuall home in the new disk and then mount it in /home (as /home is not mounted)

Answer (score 1):

You can not easily expand your partitions unless you are already using [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29). As an easy solution, you can mount the extra capacity you have as another partition and make use of it.